# Update command against parent DataTable accepting changes on child Datatable?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I have a parent-child relation setup between two tables. The parent table is setup with an auto increment value for its primary key. This is working fine and the new row in the parent DataTable is refreshed with the actual value of the key that was just inserted when I call `Update` on the TableAdaptor.

The problem is that the rows from the child table are not being inserted into the DB. For debug purposes, I added `changesBefore` and `changesAfter` to the code sample to see what changed rows exist in the child table. When I step through the code with a debugger, `changesBefore` constains the new child rows. `changesAfter` is `Nothing`.  Its almost as if calling `Update` against the header table is triggering `AcceptChanges` on the child table.

I am familiar with insert/updating with DataTables and TableAdapters but this is my first attempt at using an autoincrement on a parent table. What am I missing here?

```
        Dim changesBefore = _ds.ResponseDetails.GetChanges

        headersTa.Update(_ds.ResponseHeaders)

        Dim changesAfter = _ds.ResponseDetails.GetChanges

        detailsTa.Update(_ds.ResponseDetails)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working now. Turns out there is an `AcceptRejectRule` property for each relation in a data set. I had the rule set to `Cascade` so it was basically cascading `AcceptChanges` down to the child table when `Update` was called against the parent. Changing the rule to `None` resolved my issue.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.acceptrejectrule(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

After doing the header update, you need to update the linking field in the detail record with the auto generated id from the header record.  This does not happen automatically for you.

Comment: I did setup a relationion the DataSet so so the linking field is being updated. I confirmeded this by putting on _ds.ResponseDetails after calling Update against the parent. The child rows have the correct value for the parent's PK in the linking field. The problem appears to be that the Update agains the child table doesn't save anything because it doesn't think the table has rows with changes.